# how to generate getter on boolean using swagger-codegen-maven plugin

Tags: java, swagger-codegen

I'm using `swagger-codegen-maven`(`3.0.29`) plugin to generate code. However, I see that `boolean` is generated with `isXXX` instead of `getXXX`. Is there a way to generate `getXXX`.

swagger code

```
 Data:
    required:
      - id
    properties:
      verified:
        description: >-
          Id
        example: true
        pattern: ^true|false$
        type: boolean
```

generated code

```
  @NotNull
  @Schema(example = "true", required = true)
  public Boolean isVerified() {
    return verified;
  }

  public void setVerified(Boolean verified) {
    this.verified = verified;
  }

}
```

Comment: Update to 3.1.x and you [should be fine](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/migration-guide.adoc#from-30x-to-310)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their github issues, that enhancement is available on 3.1.x of OpenAPI-generator and that will have to be implemented on swagger-codegen-maven which currently seems to be not implemented.

> Version 3.1.0 is the first minor version of OpenAPI-Generator, in comparison to 3.0.3 it contains some breaking changes, but with the possibility to fallback to the old behavior. The default value of some options might change. Projects relying on generated code might need to be adapted.

Please, check out the issues.

1. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7764
2. https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/432
3. https://github.com/jmini/openapi-generator/blob/6fca5f5aa0d863fbe9ec013448c5f4f24206397d/docs/migration-guide.adoc

Comment: I don't see a 3.1.x version of swagger-codegen-maven plugin

Comment: Indeed.

`Version 3.1.0 is the first minor version of OpenAPI-Generator, in comparison to 3.0.3 it contains some breaking changes, but with the possibility to fallback to the old behavior. The default value of some options might change. Projects relying on generated code might need to be adapted.`

Answer (score 0):

The author of the question asked a solution for "swagger-codegen-maven" which is not the openAPI generator. Actually, the openAPI variation for code generation fixed this specific issue, while swagger codegen still did not:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/pull/599

I used a shell script command on the generated files:

sed -i'' -e 's/Boolean is/Boolean get/g' $(find generated-sources/src/main/java/com/company//module/openapi/ -type f)